# Pivoting in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have

```
SalesOrderId    Partners    PartnerType
1                   A            1
1                   B            2
2                   X            1
2                   Y            2
```

I need

```
SalesOrdeId Reseller    Distrubutor ResellerType    DistributorType
1              A              B           1                2
2              X              Y           1                2
```

N.B.~ Reseller Type = 1, Distributor Type = 2

Is it possible to achieve this using pivoting?

**DDL**

```
declare @t table(SalesOrderId int,Partners Varchar(10),PartnerType int)
Insert into @t values(1,'A',1),(1,'B',2),(2,'X',1),(2,'Y',2)
select *
From @t
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select SalesOrderId,
       max(case PartnerType when 1 then Partners end) as Reseller,
       max(case PartnerType when 2 then Partners end) as Distributor,
       1 as ResellerType,
       2 as DistributorType
from @t
group by SalesOrderId
```